# Basic Charles proxy ssl clarification

Tags: android, ssl, encryption, charles-proxy

This is probably a basic question. I'm running an android device through Charles proxy, running apps, and capturing the packets using wireshark. In the URL heading for some of the traffic going through I can see the number of SSL handshakes, then when looking at the specific requests/responses to the URL, some of them also have information for SSL handshakes.

Basically, are the requests and responses going out without any info in the SSL handshake field unencrypted? I'm trying to determine if the body of some of the requests is being sent out encrypted or unencrypted.

In the attached image, if the protocl is HTTP and the SSL is TLSv 1.2 but there is no info in the SSL handshake field, is the request/response still encrypted?

[pictures of charles proxy overview tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iGp8.png)